# Qt: Moving entries between two QListViews from one QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, c++, qt, sqlite, pyqt

My Sqlite database looks like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE Scene(
    sceneID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Character(
    characterID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    fullName TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE CharacterInScene(
    characterID INTEGER,
    sceneID INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(characterID, sceneID),
    FOREIGN KEY(characterID) REFERENCES Character(characterID),
    FOREIGN KEY(sceneID) REFERENCES Scene(sceneID)
);
INSERT INTO Scene (1, "Police Station");
INSERT INTO Character (1, "Harrison Ford");
INSERT INTO Character (2, "Rutger Hauer");
INSERT INTO CharacterInScene(1, 1);
```

So, I have a single scene, "Police Station" which contains Harrison Ford, but not Rutger Hauer. In my UI, I'm editing the contents of that one scene. And have an interface like this:

[image: UI]

Right now, these are two QListViews connected to two QSqlQueryModels with the following queries:

```
1. SELECT * FROM Character WHERE characterID NOT IN
    (SELECT characterID FROM CharacterInScene WHERE sceneID=1)
2. SELECT * FROM Character WHERE characterID IN
    (SELECT characterID FROM CharacterInScene WHERE sceneID=1)
```

I want the arrow buttons to move a selected entry from one list to the other, and the apply button to execute the change in the db. But because of the read-only nature of QSqlQueryModel, this isn't really tenable as I have it set now.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I assume I'll want to implement my own QSqlTableModel, but I'm not sure how, and I haven't been able to find any good examples similar to my situation. Maybe I'm overthinking it.

I'm working in PyQt5, but I can translate from C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to implement any custom model or make `QSqlQueryModel` editable, the insertion and deletion of records. You can do this task with `QSqlQuery` and call the update of the models.

```
def addToScene(self):
    for ix in self.notInScene.listView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes():
        id = self.notInScene.model.record(ix.row()).value("characterID")
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO CharacterInScene VALUES (:characterID, :sceneID);")
        query.bindValue(":characterID", id)
        query.bindValue(":sceneID", self.sceneId)
        if not query.exec_():
            print(query.lastError().text())

    self.updateList() # update the model

def removeFromScene(self):
    for ix in self.inScene.listView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes():
        id = self.inScene.model.record(ix.row()).value("characterID")
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("DELETE FROM CharacterInScene WHERE characterID = :characterID AND sceneID = :sceneID;")
        query.bindValue(":characterID", id)
        query.bindValue(":sceneID", self.sceneId)
        if not query.exec_():
            print(query.lastError().text())
    self.updateList() # update the model
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47024950)

Comment: Extremely complete answer, thank you. This, along with some transaction handling, is exactly what was needed.